# Is there a cross-platform way to get ssid and bssid of a WLAN network through C++

Tags: c++, ssid, bssid

I have created a cross-platform c++ app that among other things need to get the ssid and the bssid of the wlan network that is up. I have found ways to accomplish that in windows (WMI,WLanSCAN) and in linux (executing and parsing the relevant shell commands) as well. So I wonder whether there is a library or api that can get ssid and bssid in a cross-platform way?

Comment: Well if you have the OS specific pieces you can abstract them behind your own common interface and use the preprocessor to only compile the OS specific part with flags.

Comment: http://libtins.github.io does what you ask, although it might be overkill.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes I know that but I was just wondering whether there is already a library that already does this

Comment: @Gill Bates , what exactly do you mean by overkill?

Comment: @dk13 It can do much more than just what you ask of it.